# SOAP request is not working on cross network

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, soap-client

I am using AXIS 1 for creating a stub. I am trying to create a standalone application to call another web service.

Scenario:
I am working X network and I am using SOAP service of Y client. Y client SOAP service is working on Y client network, but when I try to connect to it on my local network, it's giving below exception as response:

Can anyone help me on this. I am struggling for 10 days to find the root cause of this issue.

Below commented response and exception:

XML response from client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"; xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">; 
  <soapenv:Body> 
    <soapenv:Fault> 
      <faultcode xmlns:ns1="xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:HTTP</faultcode>;       
      <faultstring>(0)null</faultstring> 
      <detail> 
        <string>return code: 0 </string> 
        <ns2:HttpErrorCode xmlns:ns2="xml.apache.org/axis/">0</ns2:HttpErrorCode>; 
      </detail> 
    </soapenv:Fault> 
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The occuring exception is:

> Exception : AxisFault faultCode: {xml.apache.org/axis}
>   HTTP faultSubcode: faultString: (0)null faultActor: faultNode: faultDetail: {}:return code: 0 {xml.apache.org/axis}HttpErrorCode:0 (0)null at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTT‌​PSender.java:744) at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.‌​java:144) at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(Invocati‌​onStrategy.java:32)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789) to include all relevant information to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including any code samples and error messages that will help us to form a useful answer. Do not add code or error messages as comments as this makes it difficult to read and understand.

Comment: I incorporated two snippets from the comment section and improved some formatting.

Comment: @grimthorr Thanks for replay.

This problem is due to less  access to server IP address. So I take access to IP hence problem go resolved.

Thank you for your response.